# Enabling plug and play DSI displays with Yocto for Compute Module 4

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, yocto, bitbake, lcd

So I built a new X11 Langdale 4.1.3 Yocto image and the HDMI output works just fine. However I have a 5" and 7" DSI display that are supposed to work without drivers.

There are two overlays that you need to enable to make the displays work.

dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d

dtoverlay=vc4-kms-dsi-7inch

I installed Raspberry Pi OS and when I make these changes to the config.txt file the displays work just fine. However when I use the exact same config and hardware setup with our X11 Yocto image the displays do not work.

Do I need to do something specific when building Yocto to enable the DSI displays?

I saw a post about adding this to the local.conf is this correct?

RASPBERRYPI_DISPLAY = "1"

EDIT:

**I ran the following command and then rebooted and the display now outputs the bootup text and shows the raspberry pi logo so thats awesome. However it will not boot into the X11 window manager and show the terminal that should pop up.**

```
sudo wget https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/cmio/dt-blob-disp1- 
only.bin -O /boot/dt-blob.bin
```

**The touchscreen works I can plug in the hdmi and use the DSI touch screen to move the cursor around. I'm not seeing a picture though.**

**Any ideas what I can try next? Maybe my config file is not correct and thus the screen isn't working?**